# starting with netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am starting with netsuite. I have following questions :

1. What is netsuite (I know it provides cloud based software as a service but how)?
2. If I am a developer, what all I can do with netsuite and how ?

I am not getting what actually is netsuite.

Thanks

Comment: As someone who is helping out with working on a Netsuite eCommerce store, the only advice I can give is to RUN AWAY. RUN AWAY AND DON'T LOOK BACK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NetSuite is an Enterprise Resource Planning ([ERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning)) system. It is a very large and complex online application that is also very customizable.

Really, the best place to learn NetSuite is in NetSuite. By far the best reference I use on a daily basis is the [NetSuite Usergroup](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/index.php). Apply for membership there. The UG is very active with users, developers and NetSuite employees. You will need a valid NetSuite account login to register.

Also, if you are a developer working for a company that is using NS for their ERP, then you might want to look into taking the SuiteScript class. There are also many training videos on the NetSuite corporate site.

Answer (score 2):

Netsuite is a cloud based accounting software, integrated ERP/CRM solution. It also have an eCommerce module, very flexible in terms of customization. You can use their own API to create an automate processes. Webservices, REST are all possible for integration.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite provides a lot of documentation in their Help section, along with sample code etc. The User group is something you would definitely want to join. I don't recommend taking their SuiteScript class unless you have an unlimited budget and/or have no programming skills. If you are a developer, then simply using their Help documentation (now public at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/index.html#bridgehead_4141385928) should suffice.